# Why \% unable to use in table, overlap (Table alignment)

Tags: tables, tabulary

I tried to type % in my table, but its overlaps.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}

\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}

\usepackage{makecell,siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document} 

\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\sisetup{table-format=3.0, table-number-alignment=left, table-column-width=2.0cm}
 \begin{tabular}{lSS}
    \toprule
    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\thead{\makebox[0pt]{Testing 123 (\%)}}}\\ 
     \cmidrule{2-3}
    &{\small \textbf{Accuracy}}
     & {\small\textbf{Inaccuracy}} \\
     \midrule
    N       & 20    & 20 \\
    Mean    & 50.45\%  & 58.55\% \\
    Median  & 78.74\% & 665.26\% \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Usually you put the unit as part of the heading, i.e. `\textbf{Accuracy in \si{\percent}}`

Comment: `table-format` should be, respectively `2.2` and `3.2`. If you mean that `20` in the first row is *not* a percentage, just centre it with `{20}`.

Comment: @HenriMenke what is the different between `\si{\percent}` and `\%`?

Comment: @Bernard, what is the different in `table-format` for `2.2` and `3.2`?

Comment: @aan Semantic vs. explicit markup.

Comment: `2.2` saves the necessary space for numbers with 2 digits in the integer part, and 2 in the decimal part. For `3.2`, it is respectively  3 and 2 digits.

Comment: @HenriMenke: Furthermore `\SI{10}{\percent}`, for instance, is the equivalent of `10\,\%`, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @Bernard, I had changed the `table-format` to `2.2` and make the first row which is not % to `{20}` to centre. How can I make `20` to left-hand side alight?

Comment: Using `\multicolumn{1}{l}{20}` or `{\makecell[l]{20}}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're reserving a wrong number of digits.

Also, there should be no % sign in the header if not all table entries express percentages.
The entries that are not percentages should not be aligned at the decimal point.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document} 

\begin{table}[htp!]
\centering

\begin{tabular}{
  l
  S[table-format=2.2,table-space-text-post=\%]
  S[table-format=3.2,,table-space-text-post=\%]
}
\toprule
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{Testing 123} \\ 
\cmidrule{2-3}
& \textbf{Accuracy}
& \textbf{Inaccuracy} \\
\midrule
N       & {20}  &  {20}      \\
Mean    & 50.45\% &  58.55\% \\
Median  & 78.74\% & 665.26\% \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry to interrupt, both the numbers `20` are not aligned with decimal alignment, is it ignore?

Comment: @MadyYuvi, it should not be aligned, since they are different type of data.

Comment: @Zarko Thanks for the clarification...

Answer (score 2):

This can be done by using `dcolumn` package instead of `siunitx`, below are the modified tags:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}

\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}

\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}}%
\begin{document} 

\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
 \begin{tabular}{ld{2,3}d{3,3}}
    \toprule
    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Testing 123 (\%)}\\ 
     \cmidrule{2-3}
    &\multicolumn{1}{c}{\small \textbf{Accuracy}}
     & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\small\textbf{Inaccuracy}} \\
     \midrule
    N       & 20    & 20 \\
    Mean    & 50.45\%  & 58.55\% \\
    Median  & 78.74\% & 665.26\% \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: hm, numbers "20" should be centered. This is usual way when someone present some statistic results (N is number of samples). Or I'm wrong?

Comment: @Zarko, yes, correct. N is number of samples. Should be all center. Thanks!